# What is Futures.transform() lambda argument in case the original ApiFuture / ListenableFuture failed or cancelled

Tags: java, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, guava, future

I have a method that sends asynchronously a list of messages. Each send returns `ApiFuture<String>` (GCP version of Guava's `ListenableFuture`). I need this method to return one `Future<Boolean>`, so I

1. Create a list dependency on each `ApiFuture<String>`
2. Transform the resulting `ApiFuture<List<String>>` to a `Future<Boolean>` using `ApiFutures.transform` method

---

```
ApiFuture< List < String > > allSentFuture = ApiFutures.allAsList(futures);
return ApiFutures.transform(allSentFuture, val -> { 
        return true; 
    }, 
    Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
);
```

My question is: what is the value of `val` argument of the lambda above if one or more of the original futures are failed/cancelled? Is the lambda even called in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not called.

Comment: @CliveEvans what happens then if a caller calls wait() on the final result future? Exception is thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ApiFuture<V>` forms a *monad* over the type `V`, and `transform` applies a function to the encapsulated value of type `V`. If the `ApiFuture<V>` does not contain a `V` value because it is failed or cancelled, then the transformed future is the same.

If you want to handle failures due to exceptions, you can use `ApiFutures.catching()` to produce an alternative result (e.g. `Boolean.FALSE`) instead.

If you want to transform cancellation into a successful value, I believe you would need to use `ApiFuture.addListener` directly, and have the listener complete a `SettableApiFuture` which you return. Then the listener (which will get called when the source future is cancelled) can check `isCancelled` to detect this case, or can catch and handle the `CancellationException`.

For example:

```
/**
 * Adapt an iterable of {@link ApiFuture} instances into a single {@code ApiFuture}.
 */
static <T> ApiFuture<Boolean> adaptFutures(Iterable<ApiFuture<T>> futures) {
    final SettableApiFuture<Boolean> result = SettableApiFuture.create();
    final ApiFuture<List<T>> allFutures = ApiFutures.allAsList(futures);
    allFutures.addListener(
        () -> {
            if (allFutures.isCancelled()) {
                result.set(Boolean.FALSE);
                return;
            }
            try {
                allFutures.get();
                result.set(Boolean.TRUE);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
                // Maybe log something here?
                //
                // Note that InterruptedException is actually impossible here
                // because we're running in the listener callback, but the API
                // still marks it as potentially thrown by .get() above.
                //
                // So if we reach here it means that the allAsList future failed.
                result.set(Boolean.FALSE);
            }
        },
        // Not normally safe, but we know our listener runs fast enough
        // to run inline on the thread that completes the last future.
        Runnable::run);
    return result;
}
```